# NSMutableArray multidimensional, removeAllObjects?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

```
ObjC w/ARC
```

Do I need to call `removeAllObjects` on a previously initialized `NSMutableArray` (which is setup to be multidimensional, btw) before I reassign a new instance of `NSMutableArray` to it?

Consider:

```
@interface MyClass
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(instancetype)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initializeMyArrayWithData]  // once
        [self initializeMyArrayWithData]  // twice
    } 
    return self;
}

-(void)initializeMyArrayWithData {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        [temp addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8]];
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            [[temp objectAtIndex:row] insertObject:@"TEST" atIndex:col];
        }
    }

    // let's assume my array was previously initialized
    // with this method. Do I need to "clean-up" the previous
    // instance by removing all objects within it, or will
    // this be handled automatically by the property method using
    // the following simple assignment?

    self.MyArray = temp;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to do this. Here is what happens: ARC will tell the current instance of `NSMutableArray` referenced in `self.MyArray` that it has been released. Assuming that it is the only reference, the array will start deallocating its content, releasing each of its objects.